# Read application crash reports? My iPad app doesn't even start

Tags: crash-reports

Hi guys I recently added a device to my provisioning profile (an iPad) and wanted to test my application out on it. The problem is that it doesn't even start up. It just crashes right away. I can add that I did the "Upgrade current target to iPad" and it runs fine on the simulator. I read something about not handeling exceptions but doesn't even know where to start when I know nothing of reading the crash report. My theory is that you have to modify the provisioning profile with the wild card bundle identifier to get the application going on more that one device. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this bad boy:

```
Incident Identifier: EA70E168-4C32-4ACF-9C4C-3FAEE49408D1
CrashReporter Key:   a1af6c33097cd7fc5cddd6e893bfdaa65405bd86
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         ErrorReport [213]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CB4CCC6F-3914-46FE-92D4-FA06BD768F37/ErrorReport.app/ErrorReport
Identifier:      ErrorReport
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-18 15:28:20.128 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac07c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33ac07fc +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
12  UIKit                           0x3224b77c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1104
13  UIKit                           0x3224cb32 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 86
14  UIKit                           0x321a08de -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 30
15  UIKit                           0x3219fcb2 -[UIViewController loadView] + 74
16  UIKit                           0x320a0220 -[UIViewController view] + 24
17  UIKit                           0x320acd04 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 16
18  UIKit                           0x320acb74 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
19  UIKit                           0x320aca72 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 18
20  UIKit                           0x320ac54a -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 374
21  UIKit                           0x320ac358 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 176
22  UIKit                           0x320ac29c -[UINavigationController viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 8
23  UIKit                           0x320ac238 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 132
24  UIKit                           0x320750c8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 20
25  CoreFoundation                  0x33a5ebb8 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
26  QuartzCore                      0x3410867e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 114
27  QuartzCore                      0x34108436 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 178
28  QuartzCore                      0x34102566 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 206
29  QuartzCore                      0x3410237c CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
30  QuartzCore                      0x3410ce48 CA::Transaction::flush() + 40
31  QuartzCore                      0x34109b6e +[CATransaction flush] + 18
32  UIKit                           0x320ac038 -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 24
33  UIKit                           0x3209a310 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 456
34  UIKit                           0x32066484 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
35  UIKit                           0x32065ec2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
36  UIKit                           0x32065900 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
37  GraphicsServices                0x33b0eefc PurpleEventCallback + 660
38  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
39  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
40  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
41  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
42  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
43  UIKit                           0x32099302 -[UIApplication _run] + 374
44  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
45  ErrorReport                     0x00002a98 0x1000 + 6808
46  ErrorReport                     0x00002a4c 0x1000 + 6732

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd79e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd7364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e3d52e8
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3497f989      r6: 0x0014459c      r7: 0x2fdfcd60
    r8: 0x3eb5c538    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0011cb30     r11: 0x344cdec5
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfcd60      lr: 0x30d7c2cb      pc: 0x30d7c2d4
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0xbfff +ErrorReport armv7   /var/mobile/Applications/CB4CCC6F-3914-46FE-92D4-FA06BD768F37/ErrorReport.app/ErrorReport
   0x8d000 -    0x8efff  dns.so armv7   /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7   /usr/lib/dyld
0x3001f000 - 0x30026fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30054000 - 0x3016afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x302b7000 - 0x30366fff  WebKit armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x303fc000 - 0x3051cfff  CoreGraphics armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3056b000 - 0x3056bfff  vecLib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30641000 - 0x30700fff  CFNetwork armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3076f000 - 0x307c4fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x307e6000 - 0x307e8fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30821000 - 0x30853fff  AppSupport armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30854000 - 0x30854fff  Accelerate armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3091c000 - 0x30931fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30b44000 - 0x30b46fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30c45000 - 0x30c74fff  SystemConfiguration armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30d03000 - 0x30e14fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30e37000 - 0x30f1ffff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30f20000 - 0x30f2bfff  libz.1.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31066000 - 0x31114fff  QuartzCore armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x31161000 - 0x31280fff  Foundation armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31307000 - 0x31347fff  CoreAudio armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x318b5000 - 0x318d5fff  PrintKit armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31bd9000 - 0x31c02fff  MobileCoreServices armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31c6d000 - 0x31d16fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31d29000 - 0x31d2cfff  IOSurface armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31d2d000 - 0x31d2ffff  MobileInstallation armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31d46000 - 0x31d4dfff  AggregateDictionary armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31e09000 - 0x31e4bfff  CoreTelephony armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x320c4000 - 0x320d0fff  GraphicsServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33ae9000 - 0x33aebfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33b49000 - 0x33c82fff  AudioToolbox armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33d2c000 - 0x33d2ffff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33d30000 - 0x33d31fff  CoreSurface armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x33d61000 - 0x33d7afff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x340dc000 - 0x34112fff  CoreText armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3415c000 - 0x3418ffff  AddressBook armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x341a5000 - 0x34526fff  UIKit armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34527000 - 0x345bafff  ImageIO armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34632000 - 0x34636fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34775000 - 0x34822fff  JavaScriptCore armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x34852000 - 0x3485bfff  CoreVideo armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3492e000 - 0x3493afff  SpringBoardServices armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3493d000 - 0x34987fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34a7d000 - 0x34b3efff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34b3f000 - 0x35127fff  WebCore armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3520f000 - 0x352fcfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x353e7000 - 0x353ecfff  MobileKeyBag armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3549d000 - 0x354d5fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35553000 - 0x35560fff  OpenGLES armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x355b6000 - 0x355bcfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x357da000 - 0x358c0fff  CoreFoundation armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35992000 - 0x3599ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x35b60000 - 0x35babfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35bac000 - 0x35e46fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3601b000 - 0x3603afff  Bom armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3603d000 - 0x360acfff  ProofReader armv7   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3612f000 - 0x36137fff  libkxld.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x36138000 - 0x3616ffff  Security armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x36170000 - 0x361bdfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x361be000 - 0x361f8fff  IOKit armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3623f000 - 0x3627efff  libGLImage.dylib armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
```

please help me guys!

Answer (score 0):

Can't really solve your question, but can give you more info because I have quite the same problem. My app got rejected (after the 3th try) and got the exact same crash report you are giving. The app would crash on launch, but on my device and simulator it runs ok. The technical support gave me this advice, but I was unable to test the submitted version on the device, also I didn't notice files that would be missing:

The most common problem loading nib files is that the file is missing. You might want to inspect the .app that you submitted to App Review, to see that it has all the .nib files inside that you would expect.

Sometimes differences in build configurations mean that a file that is present during debugging might be missing when making your final build. cTo be sure you're testing the exact build of the app that you submit to the App Store, you can create an Archived build, that you can both test, and submit. In Xcode 4, Product -> Archive will archive a build of your app. You can test that build by "Sharing" it with yourself (ie putting an ad-hoc build on your device) from the Organizer window in Xcode.

Comment: Found out what was wrong. I forgot to change in interface builder after I reformatted a class from lower case to uppe case. Did it for me.